# Python - Pandas - Copy column names to new dataframe without bringing data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes, one called 'data' and other called 'output_data'. 'data' has some info that looks like:

```
Name 5:10 6:10 7:10
John   5    7   9
Matt   3    4   7
Bill   8    2   3
```

What I want in output_data is:

```
Name 5:10 6:10 7:10
John          
Matt          
Bill
```

I'll then be programmatically updating each of those cell values based on a calculation from the value in 'data'. I've been attempting to start with just getting all of the column names copied using this code:

```
#copy column headers
headers = data.columns
data.rename(index = headers, inplace = True)
```

my understanding with rename() is that it accepts an index an argument but I keep getting an error stating:

> 'Index' object is not callable

I'm pretty new to pandas and python in general so this is probably something easy and I'm just missing a core concept somewhere. I did try searching for an answer but either it did not quite address what I'm looking for, or maybe I didn't understand the solution. Any help is greatly appreciated.

edit:
to give more context, the new dataframe values are going to be a rate of change that will have more values added over time. So the final sheet will be:

```
Name 5:10 6:10 7:10
John   0% +40% +28%    
Matt   0% +33% +75%     
Bill   0% -75% +50%
```

it will also ultimately have a few thousand entries as more data is added over time. So I'll end up with one dataframe that contains all of the raw data, and another that has the percent change from hour to hour

Comment: Why not just `df.copy()` and ignore the values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
new_df = df.copy()
new_df[['5:10', '6:10', '7:10']] = ''
```

or more concise:

```
new_df = df.copy()
new_df[new_df.columns[1:]] = ''
```

---

But why not just create a new dataframe with `new_df = df.copy()` and then perform your computations without blanking the dataframe? I don't think you need to do that, and it just adds time to the process.

Comment: the sample I provided is a small list of what the full data is. This dataframe will ultimately have a few thousand columns in it. That's why I want to be able to copy them programmatically.

eventually, I'll be editing an existing data frame and adding a new column and updating new values using all of the old values.

Comment: So does my solution not work? You don't have to specify the columns manually like the first example shows. If you give me details about your columns and what columns and which one(s) you want to keep the values of, I can write code for that.

Comment: I think I'm confused about what the argument 1: is signifying in
```
new_df.columns[1:]
```
I came to python from c++ so I'm still getting a hang of the syntax

Comment: The code:
`output_data = [output_data.columns[1:]] = ''` 
gives an error stating:
"not enough values to unpack (expected 1, got 0)

Comment: No problem! In C++ you can only use simple values to index array, but in Python, while you can do that too, you can also use [`slice`](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-slice)s. Basically they're just a combination of start, stop, and step, all of which are options. By saying `new_df.columns[1:]` I'm just selecting all of `new_df`'s columns, except for the 1st one.

Comment: The code `output_data = [output_data.columns[1:]] = ''` is not valid. You probably meant something like this: `output_data2 = output_data.copy()`, then on a new line: `output_data2[output_data2.columns[1:]] = ''`

Comment: Also, with Pandas specifically, you can index dataframes using _lists_. So if you say `df[['col1', 'col2']]` you get a new dataframe containing _just_ those two columns and their values. So `new_df[new_df.columns[1:]]` selects all columns except the first.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. This appears to have fixed it. I still have a lot to learn! Appreciate all the help!
`#save column headers
output_data = data.copy()
output_data[output_data.columns[1:]] = ''
`

Answer (score 1):

Create a new dataframe with only specific data

```
old_data_frame= ....OLD_DATA_FRAME_CONSTRUCTION....
new_dataFrame = pd.DataFrame(columns=old_data_frame.columns, index=old_data_frame.index)
```

Only to mention all cells will be placed with NaN values

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't preserve the first column's values as I need in my use case. But good to see an alternative way to construct the dataframe

Comment: you need to use __Name__ column as index

Answer (score 0):

**Pandas Copy Column Names From One Data Frame To Another**

Use the syntax DataFrame[[*column_names]] to return a new DataFrame with the desired columns from DataFrame. Call pandas.DataFrame.copy() with the new DataFrame as DataFrame to return a deep-copy of DataFrame.

https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-copy-columns-to-a-new-pandas-dataframe-in-python

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"colA":[33,1,71],"colB":[75,52,7],"colC":[22,95,68]})
x = df['largest2'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(2).iloc[1], axis=1)

#print(x)
col_names = list(df)
#for col_name in col_names:
#print(col_names)

selected_columns = col_names
new_df = selected_columns.copy()
print(new_df)
```

[image: Column Names From One Data Frame To Another]